# Handling Excel export and saving in desired location

Tags: php, html, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I would like to extend my question from
[Read php file using php file and excel export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056189/read-php-file-using-php-file-and-excel-export).

If I open the following PHP file in Firefox, it shows a popup message asking where to save the Excel file.
If I open the file in Google Chrome, it saves it automatically without any popup, in my download (C: Drive) folder.

```
    <?php
    $read_file = readfile("my_export_file.php");
    $file = 'test.xls';
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    echo $read_file;
    ?>
```

What I want is:

1. Save the file in C: /Data/test.xls
2. There should be no popup whenever I run my file rather it should save in the desired location.

How can I do this?

Comment: No! You're out of luck..... this horrible little thing called security is a major hassle.... it's annoying that it won't let you save a file directly in a folder on the user's PC regardless of the operating system they're using, or whether it will overwrite their system files or password files without telling them

Comment: oh. too bad. bad thing.. anyway thanks for the explanation. atleast i'm clear that this is not possible..